# How to get Id values for the adjacent records in TcxGrid (TcxGridDBTableView)

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-2009, tcxgrid

I have DevExpress cxGrid and I would like to get the Ids of the adjacent records. I can use them in the following use case: user deletes focused record and I position the (grid view) cursor on one of the adjacent records (as determined but the current sorting and grouping order of the grid view). Otherwise the position of the grid cursor is poorly determined after removal of the record and after refreshing the grid view.

I have made the following attempts but they are not working - the Id values are junk:

```
procedure GetAdjacentRecordIds(AView: TcxGridDBTableView; ACdFieldName: string; var APrevId, AId, ANextId: Integer);
var Item: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
    RecIdx: Integer;
    i, RecCount: Integer;
begin
  APrevId:=-1;
  AId:=-1;
  ANextId:=-1;

  if Trim(AIdFieldName)='' then Exit;
  if not Assigned(AView) then Exit;
  if not Assigned(AView.DataController) then Exit;

  Item:=AView.DataController.GetItemByFieldName(UpperCase(AIdFieldName));
  if not Assigned(Item) then Exit;

  {//First attempt, didn't work, AId was the right one, but APrevId and ANextId were junk
  RecIdx:=AView.DataController.FocusedRecordIndex;
  AId:=AView.DataController.Values[RecIdx, Item.Index];
  APrevId:=AView.DataController.Values[RecIdx-1, Item.Index];
  ANextId:=AView.DataController.Values[RecIdx+1, Item.Index];}

  //Second attempt, doesn't work, all three Ids are junk
  RecIdx:=-1;
  RecCount:=AView.ViewData.RecordCount;
  for i:=0 to RecCount-1 do begin
    if AView.ViewData.Records[i].Focused then begin
      RecIdx:=1;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
  if RecIdx<0 then Exit;

  AId:=AView.ViewData.Records[RecIdx].Values[Item.Index];
  if RecIdx>0 then
    APrevId:=AView.ViewData.Records[RecIdx-1].Values[Item.Index];
  if RecIdx<RecCount then
    ANextId:=AView.ViewData.Records[RecIdx+1].Values[Item.Index];
end;
```

How can I correct this code to get the field values for adjacent records. Or maybe I should use Grid navigator and do prev/next on it, but I would like to find the values in invisible. And DataSet.DisableControls may stop the Grid navigator?

Answer (score 0):

I used the DevExpress knowledgebase to find this answer. You are referencing the internal storage of the grid incorrectly. You can also use `dataset.previous` and `dataset.next` to position the record pointer in a bound grid, and simply use `dataset.fieldbyname(AidFieldName).AsInteger` to retrieve key values.

[get-cell-value-by-column-name](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q143712/get-cell-value-by-column-name)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);  
var  
  AColumn: TcxGridDBColumn;  
  I: Integer;  
  AView: TcxGridDBTableView;  
  v: Variant;  
begin  
 AView := cxGrid1DBTableView1;  
 AColumn := TcxGridDBColumn( AView.FindItemByName('cxGrid1DBTableView1Capital'));  
 if Assigned(AColumn) then  
   for I := 0 to  AView.ViewData.RowCount - 1 do  
     v := AView.DataController.Values[AView.ViewData.Rows[0].RecordIndex, AColumn.Index];  
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of the navigation functions of DataSet is not the solution, because CxGrid can have completely different sorting order. But DataController navigation is good solution and there is no visual flickering as well. So, the solution is:

```
  RecIdx:=AView.DataController.FocusedRecordIndex;
  AId:=AView.DataController.Values[RecIdx, Item.Index];
  if not AView.DataController.IsBOF then begin
    AView.DataController.GotoPrev;
    RecIdx:=AView.DataController.FocusedRecordIndex;
    APrevId:=AView.DataController.Values[RecIdx, Item.Index];
    AView.DataController.GotoNext;
  end;
  if not AView.DataController.IsEOF then begin
    AView.DataController.GotoNext;
    RecIdx:=AView.DataController.FocusedRecordIndex;
    ANextId:=AView.DataController.Values[RecIdx, Item.Index];
    AView.DataController.GotoPrev;
  end;
```